# Why is $Q(F_{n}(Z)\to F(Z))\geq Q(Z\notin N)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_{n})_{n}, X$ be real random variables on probability space  space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} X, n \to \infty$. Further let $(\Sigma, \mathcal{G}, Q)$ be a probability space where $Z$ is a random variable with standard normal distribution.

Show that

$Q(F_{n}(Z)\to F(Z))=1$

Let $N$ be the countable set where $F$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb R\setminus N$.

Why is it true that:

$Q(F_{n}(Z)\to F(Z))\geq  Q(Z\notin N)=1$

I particularly do not understand the $\geq $ inequality.

Comment: What are $F_n$?  Are they defined in terms of (say) $X_n$ and $F$ somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $F_n$ and $F$ are distribution functions of $X_n$ and $X$. Given the condition $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$, **by definition** of convergence in distribution and the set $N$, that means 
\begin{equation}
F_n(z) \to F(z) \text{ for all } z \notin N. \tag{*}
\end{equation}

Rephrase $(*)$ in terms of set notation, that is 
\begin{equation}
\{z: z \notin N\} \subset \{z: F_n(z) \to F(z)\}.
\end{equation}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I do not understand why $Q(\{Z \notin N\})=1$. I know that $Z$ is continuous because it has standard normal distrbution but how did this have any relation to the set $N$, since $N$ is defined in terms of $F_{n}$ and $F$, so it has nothing to do with $Z$?

Comment: Use $N$ is a countable set while $Z$ is continuous.

Comment: By the way, your original question is particularly about the $\geq$.